# Is it because of insufficient reputations that "reopen" button under closed questions cannot be seen?

Tags: support, reputation, vote-to-reopen

A new user with reputation less than 50 told me that she can see no "reopen" button under a particular closed question. Is it because of insufficient reputations that "reopen" button under closed questions cannot be seen?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you need at least [250 reputation to see and cast close/reopen votes on your own questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) and at least [3000 reputation to do so on any question](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

This is a screenshot I took of one of my questions on a site where I have less than 250 reputation:

> [image: share—edit—delete—flag buttons]

New users can still cause their own questions to be sent to the reopen queue by [making a good edit to their recently closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36423/323179) and checking "submit for review". If that doesn't work, then asking on meta is the next step (even users under 5 rep can ask on meta as long as they are asking about something they posted on the main site).

Comment: Can I suggest a little additional wording? After “good edit”, specify “which addresses the closure reason given in the ‘on hold’ banner; and any additional details or clarification requested in the comments”. And similarly after “asking on meta”, add “again, by making an argument that after edits the question addresses the reasons for closure and now meet the site’s standards”. I’d like to avoid clogging up the reopen queue and/or meta with requests to review unchanged questions which still merit closure. It’s just double work.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Laurel](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/191178/laurel)'s [answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10715/194281), here's what it looks like when you can close/reopen questions:

> [image: share-edit-reopen-flag]